# Determining whether this series converges or diverges (2^n)/(n^n)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering how you can determine whether the following series converges or diverges?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^n}$

None of the tools I usually use seem to work on this problem (integral Test, comparison Test and ratio Test). Sorry if I'm missing something very fundamental.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am pretty sure the ratio test works. Could you show us your work?

Comment: @ Gary Thanks a lot. I got 0 as an answer, and I thought this was the critical value (when it of course was 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [root test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/roottest.aspx) is the way to go, and gives absolute convergence since

$$\sqrt[n]{\left( \frac 2 n \right)^{n}} = \frac 2 n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0 < 1$$

The [ratio test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/RatioTest.aspx) also works. Taking $a_n := (2/n)^n$, then absolute convergence follows, as

$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{2^{n+1} / (n+1)^{n+1}}{2^n / n^n}= \frac 2 n \cdot \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{n+1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0 \cdot \frac 1 e = 0 < 1$$

Comment: Could you please explain this step?
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}}{\frac{2^n}{n^n}}\right|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{2}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right|}$

Comment: Well, you get

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n} \cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$$

most immediately. The left factor becomes a $2$. If you multiply on top and bottom by $n$, then you have an $n^{n+1}$ on top, and can group the things that have an $n+1$ power together with exponent properties

Comment: Thank you! Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It converges because :
$$\forall n \geq 3, 0 \leq \dfrac{2^n}{n^n} \leq \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$$
and the geometric series :
$$\sum \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$$
converges.

Answer (score 1):

[Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test). Since
$$
\biggl( \frac{2^n}{n^n} \biggr)^{1/n} \!= \frac{2}{n} \longrightarrow 0 < 1
$$
as $n \to \infty$, the series is guaranteed to converge.

Intuitively, the terms of the series are eventually less than the terms of a geometric series with common ratio $0 < r < 1$, so the series converges by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the replies! I really appreciate it.
Here is what happened: I got $0$ as an answer when doing the ratio test. I thought this was the critical value (when of course it was $1$), so that's why I thought the ratio test didn't work.

Here is my work for those who asked for it:
$k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}}{\frac{2^n}{n^n}}\right|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{2^n}\right|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|2^{n+1-n}\cdot n^{n-\left(n+1\right)}\right|}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{2}{n}\right|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{\frac{n}{n}}\right|}=\left|\frac{0}{1}\right|=0$

Comment: Note that $a_{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ and not $\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you!